# How to solve this dictionary error in networkx2.2, python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

here's what I have in the code file:

```
  construct_CDFG(ast, CDFGS, clks, 2)
  for CDFG in CDFGS:
    cdfg_type = CDFG.node[CDFG.nodes()[0]]['typ']
    if cdfg_type == 'Always':
        cdfg_ast =  CDFG.node[CDFG.nodes()[0]]['ast']
        add_nodes_to_CDFG(cdfg_ast, CDFG)
```

It gives the KeyError: 0, full error message is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Documents/src/tool.py", line 150, in <module>
= CDFG(ast, temporal_depth, targets, clks, Params) 

File "/home/user/Documents/src/sa.py", line 477, in CDFG
cdfg_type = CDFG.node[CDFG.nodes()[0]]['typ']

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/classes/reportviews.py", line 178, in __getitem__
return self._nodes[n]

KeyError: 0
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: can you add what is the value or dict that CDFG contains?

Comment: It contains list of control data flow graph for each of the Always block in the input file.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?